Flutter integration test sharding on Firebase test labs
I have multiple test cases to run on Firebase test lab. These tests are run in two parts and takes around 30-40 minutes each. If I run these tests together there is time exceeded. I found the question but there have been no updates from flutter-team. I want to know if gcloud beta option of num-uniform-shards works for Flutter. To make it work if there is any specific version to download?
The gloud documentation has it available.
